# Turn off escaping in Symfony 2 / twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm creating a form using the form builder in Symfony. I am adding an attribute into the twig file for my checkboxes which contains an ampersand and pound sign, Symfony is automatically escaping the ampersand which stops it displaying correctly. Is there anyway to turn off escaping on a per case basis in either the twig file or the controller, or switch it off completely in the config?

```
{{ form_widget(form.checkbox, { 'attr': {'data-icon-checkmark': '&#983078;', 'data-icon-checkmark-checked': '&#983079;'} }) }}
```

I have found a few topics on this for 1.X versions of Symfony, but nothing for 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably what you need is the `raw` [tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/raw.html) or [filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html). Also take a look at the [`autoescape`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html) tag.

To turn autoescaping off globally, set the `autoescape` option to `false` in `config.yml`:

```
twig:
    # ...
    autoescape: false
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the speed response!

Answer (score 5):

You can use |raw filter.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping-in-twig