# Strings are escaped when they are saved in the database (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

In my website, I have a form to enter some information about a product, and if I use some quotes in the string, they are saved in the database with an espace character.
For example, if I enter `He's fun` in my form, I will get in the database : `He\'s fun` and this is annoying as in my view the string is rendered as `He\'s fun`

I don't understand because in my local environment I don't have this problem, the string `He's fun` will be stored as `He's fun` in my mysql DB.

What can I do to avoid this escaping issue ?

Comment: A similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846255/turn-off-escaping-in-symfony-2-twig

Comment: what does `var_dump(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'));` say? On both web and local environment

Comment: On my local environment I get : string(0) "" and on my web environment I get : string(1) "1"

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply @hek2mgl. I disable magic_quotes_gpc on my web server in the .htaccess file and it works properly now, and if I do the var_dump(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) I now get string(3) "Off"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem thanks to @hek2mgl comment turning off the magic_quotes_gpc function in my .htaccess file on the server.

For me, I have to write this : `php_value magic_quotes_gpc Off`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(){

   $var = stripslashes('He\'s fun');

   return array('var' => $var);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should write a fake controller, complete with annotations, to demonstrate how to strip the slashes from a variable before giving to twig for rendering?