# How to show font awesome icon in symfony form select

Tags: php, forms, symfony, font-awesome

I Want to show all font awesome icon in select option with Symfony Form Builder.

I add the select field with :

```
$choices = $this->getFontAwesome();
$form->add( $key, ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Texte', 'choices' => $choices, 'attr' => array('class' => "fa" ) ) );
```

My Function getFontAwesome();

```
    public function getFontAwesome(){

    $webroot = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web';
    $pattern = '/\.(fa-(?:\w+(?:-)?)+):before\s+{\s*content:\s*"\\\\(.+)";\s+}/';
    $subject =  file_get_contents( $webroot . '/assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $icons[$match[1]] = '&#x' . $match[2] . ';' ;
    }

    return $icons ;

}
```

But in the select field, don't see the icon:

Field show the code and not the icon

[image]

How i can do ?
I Try htmlspecialschars and others ( htmlentities, .. ) but don't work.

Comment: You are using select2 plugin for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't using any js plugins like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select), then you have http://jsfiddle.net/NyL7d/ this possibility, but we need work a bit to reach it.

First, to say that using `<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>` as label isn't a choice, because the `<option>` element can't have any child elements, but only text. ([see related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678760/it-is-bad-to-put-span-tags-inside-option-tags-only-for-string-manipulat))

For reusability let's build a form type named "IconChoiceType" as child of "ChoiceType":

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class IconChoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Cache for multiple icon fields or sub-requests.
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $choices;

    private $kernelRootDir;

    public function __construct($kernelRootDir)
    {
        $this->kernelRootDir = $kernelRootDir;
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // Pass this flag is necessary to render the label as raw. 
        // See below the twig field template for more details.
        $view->vars['raw_label'] = true;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'attr' => [
                // It's the key of the solution and can be done in many ways.
                // Now, the rendered <select> element will have a new font.
                'style' => "font-family: 'FontAwesome';"
            ],
            'choices' => $this->getFontAwesomeIconChoices(),
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return ChoiceType::class;
    }

    protected function getFontAwesomeIconChoices()
    {
        if (null !== $this->choices) {
            // don't to load again for optimal performance.
            // useful for multi-icon fields and sub-requests.
            return $this->choices;
        }

        // BTW we could configure the path to the "font-awesome.css".
        $fontAwesome = file_get_contents($this->kernelRootDir.'/../web/assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');

        // this regular expression only works with uncompressed version (not works with "font-awesome.min.css")
        $pattern = '/\.(fa-(?:\w+(?:-)?)+):before\s+{\s*content:\s*"\\\\(.+)";\s+}/';

        if (preg_match_all($pattern, $fontAwesome, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            foreach ($matches as list(, $class, $code)) {
                // this may vary depending on the version of Symfony, 
                // if the class name is displayed instead of the icon then swap the key/value
                $this->choices['&#x'.$code.';'] = $class;
            }
        }

        return $this->choices;

    }
}
```

and their respective service to register:

```
# app/config/service.yml
services:
    app.form.icon_choice_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ChoiceIconType
        # Symfony has already a container parameter to the kernel root directory.
        arguments: ['%kernel.root_dir%']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

well, so far there is no result different from yours.

```
<select id="form_icon" name="form[icon]" style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';">
    <option value="fa-glass">&#xf000;</option>
    <option value="fa-music">&#xf001;</option>
    ...
</select>
```

[image]

**Where is the problem now? The `<select>` font family is ready, but the icons they aren't showing, why?**

By default, in Symfony the Twig environment escapes all values that are rendered using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846255/turn-off-escaping-in-symfony-2-twig)), so we need overwrite this behavior for this form type only. For that, we create a `fields.html.twig` template in `app/Resources/views/form` directory and copy this code inside:

```
{# app/Resources/views/form/fields.html.twig #}

{# 
   here isn't need to create the expected `icon_choice_widget` like shown 
   the documentation, because this looks equal to `choice_widget` from 
   `ChoiceType`, only we need overwrite the block that renders the label. 
 #}

{%- block choice_widget_options -%}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {%- if choice is iterable -%}
            <optgroup label="{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? group_label : group_label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{- block('choice_widget_options') -}}
            </optgroup>
        {%- else -%}

            {# this line has been overwritten, see {{- block('choice_option_label') -}} to end #}
            <option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice.attr %} {% set attr = choice.attr %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endif %}{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{- block('choice_option_label') -}}</option>

        {%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endblock choice_widget_options -%}

{%- block choice_option_label -%}
    {# this block has been called from choice_widget_options block #}

    {%- if raw_label|default(false) -%}
        {# the label is rendered as raw when IconChoiceType is used #}
        {{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label|raw : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain)|raw }}
    {%- else -%}
        {{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock -%}
```

Note that `{{ choice.label|raw }}` [raw filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) displays the raw text stored (it prevents from being escaped) into label, in this case the icon font content.

finally, you need to register the form theme like describe the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field):

```
# app/config/config.yml

{# ... #}

twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

**Conclusion:**

```
$form->add('icon', IconChoiceType::class);
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know this is quite an old post and **@yceruto's** answer is correct andd has its place, but I think it's too complicated for something as simple as putting an icon on a form. Therefore, for new visitors, I offer my own version.

in formBilder

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // prepare an array with icons
    $icons =  [
        '&#xf042;',
        '&#xf170;',
    ];
    
    // decode our icons
    $icons = array_flip(array_map('html_entity_decode',$icons));
    
    // add field to formBuilder
    $builder->add('icon', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices'  => $icons,
        'mapped' => false,
    ]);

}
```

include FontAwesome library in you page and add css style

```
select { font-family: 'FontAwesome', serif }
```

[image]